# 2D Vector of Class gets error when accessing function

Tags: c++, class, vector, 2d-vector

After converting my 2D array to a 2D vector (due to all the praise I heard about it), my program breaks almost immediately, and after some testing, it appears to happen when the program tries to do a function with a vector element. I have made some simplified source code, which also has the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Dog
{
    private:
        int mass, size;
    public:
        void setMass(int);
        void setSize(int);

        int getMass();
        int getSize();
};

void Dog::setMass(int newMass) {mass = newMass;}
void Dog::setSize(int newSize) {size = newSize;}

int Dog::getMass() {return mass;}
int Dog::getSize() {return size;}

int main() 
{
    vector <vector<Dog*> > dogs(10, vector<Dog*> (10));

    dogs[0][0]->setMass(10);
    dogs[0][0]->setSize(5);
    return 0;
}
```

I also have a link to Ideone, so it is easier to test (and where I tested the code) http://ideone.com/e.js/mqVuv3

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @DanielBocksteger According to Ideone I get a runtime error, and code::blocks doesn't say anything but the process returning a really long number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 2D vector of pointer-to-Dog but are not allocating any `Dog` objects. When you initialize the 2D vector the pointers are initialized to `nullptr`. Dereferencing a `nullptr` is undefined behaviour.

Unless you have a good reason not to, I suggest you just have a 2D vector of `Dogs`:

```
vector<vector<Dog>> dogs(10, vector<Dog>(10));
```

Then you will have 100 default constructed Dogs and you can happily set their mass and size:

```
dogs[0][0].setMass(10);
dogs[0][0].setSize(5);
```

Comment: The reason I am using pointers is mostly because the internet told me to, and somewhere it says that that wouldn't work, and you have to use pointers. But thank you for pointing out my gullibility to the internet

Comment: @Orfby and now the internet is telling you to not use them! What now? :P

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz You're telling me the internet is only now telling me this? From my experience, the internet is constantly disagreeing on everything!

Comment: I disagree that the internet disagrees with itself.